# ForLoop with IF - Looping through List - Error - argument is of length zero

Tags: r

I know there are many similar responses, but I kinda cant find anything to my case.

What I did was simply make adf.test (Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test.), it created a list. Now I want to find only variables, that have p.value lower then some given value. But using for with if, gives me error. Here is reproducible example:

```
library(MTS)
my_adf_test_a <- apply(EuStockMarkets, 2, adf.test)

for(i in names(my_adf_test_a)){
  if(my_adf_test$i$p.value < 0.90) {
    print(i)
  }
}

# Error in if (my_adf_test$i$p.value < 0.9) { : argument is of length zero

# But using IF alone works.
if(my_adf_test$FTSE$p.value < 0.90) {
    print("T")
  }

# [1] "T"
```

What did I miss?
Thank you, for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `$` to access objects by their name intead use `[[`.

```
for(i in names(my_adf_test_a)){
   if(my_adf_test_a[[i]]$p.value < 0.90) {
    print(i)
   }
}
#[1] "FTSE"
```

---

Better use `sapply`/`lapply` to get `p.value`

```
sapply(my_adf_test_a, `[[`, 'p.value')
#      DAX        SMI        CAC       FTSE 
#0.95976880 0.98082442 0.99000000 0.58951395
```

You can then use `Filter` to

```
Filter(function(x) x < 0.9, sapply(my_adf_test_a, `[[`, 'p.value'))
#      FTSE 
#0.58951395
```

---

Or with `purrr:keep`

```
purrr::keep(my_adf_test_a, ~.x$p.value < 0.9)

#$FTSE

#   Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

#data:  newX[, i]
#Dickey-Fuller = -1.97355, Lag order = 12, p-value = 0.58951
#alternative hypothesis: stationary
```